# Simplifying $\log_x 25 - \left(\frac{\log_5 x}{4} - 2\log_5 x\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

My teacher gave me the following expression to change into a single expression:

$$\log_x 25 - \left(\frac{\log_5 x}{4} - 2\log_5 x\right)$$

This is what I got after working it out:

$$\log_x 25 - \log_5 \left(\frac{x}{4x^2}\right)$$

Comment: Careful with the $1/4$: you seem to be interpreting $\frac{\log_5x}4$ as $\log_5\left(\frac x4\right)$, but these are not the same thing.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Logarithms to different bases are interchangeable.  More precisely they are proportional, and one can "change base" as follows:
\begin{align*}
x&=b^{\log_bx}&\text{(definition)}\\
\log_ax&=\log_bx\log_ab&\text{(take logs of both sides)}\\
\log_bx&=\frac{\log_ax}{\log_ab}&\text{(rearrange)}.
\end{align*}
In the problem you pose, we have
$$
\log_x25=\frac{\log_{5}25}{\log_{5}x}=\frac{2}{\log_{5}x},
$$
changing between bases $x$ and $5$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\log_{x}25=\dfrac1{\log_{25}x}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
& \log_{x}25 - \left(\dfrac{\log_{5}x}{4} - 2\log_{5}x\right) \\
= & \log_{x}5^2 + \dfrac{7}{4}\log_{5}x \\
= & 2\log_{x}5 + \dfrac{7}{4}\log_{5}x \\
= & \dfrac{2}{\log_{5}x} + \dfrac{7}{4}\log_{5}x \\
= & \dfrac{7\log_{5}x + 8}{4\log_{5}x} \\
= & \dfrac{\log_{5}x^7 + \log_{5}5^8}{\log_{5}x^4} \\
= & \dfrac{\log_{5}(5^8 \cdot x^7)}{\log_{5}x^4} \\
= & \log_{x^4}(5^8 \cdot x^7) \\
\end{align}$$